# Functions defined by integrals.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I know what this says ( well sort of) they want me to take the derivative with respect to x i think? i may have to integrate with respect to y after i derivate before i can write the rest out. all n all im not really sure how to even start this problem.

Q: Given a continous function g on $\mathbb {R}$ let $h(x)= \int^{x}_{0} (x-y)e^{x-y}g(y)dy$

Show that $h^{''}-2h^{'}+h=g$

Comment: Are you familiar with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Comment: i know how to do similar questions to this where u take the derivative of the function and the derivative of the bound but i do't understand this one at all. especially the bottom part $h^{''}$ etc nfi what that even means

Comment: $h''$ means the second derivative of h. So first derivate h once, and then derivate it again to obtain $h''$.

Comment: With respect to what? x? how to i integrate this wierd busted y derivative? how do i take the total derivative of something with 2 variables in this weird form?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus which states the following: if $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt, F'(x)=f(x)$.